# angular 2 highlight text in textbox and append to the text

Tags: android, angular

Hi I want to auto select the existing text in a textbox and append to it.

The code i have here selects it on click but does not allow me to append to it; only clears the existing text once you start typing.

Any ideas?

```
<input class="form-control form-control-sm"
            (click)="$event.target.select()"
             type="text" name="name" [(ngModel)]="item.name">
```

---

EDIT

I've created the plunker below as an example but this works on the browser and not on mobile.

Use case: user has entered a typo in a text field. Clicking the text box should highlight it (which works) a further click should deselect the text and put the cursor at the end of text. This works in the browser but not on my cordova android app. Thanks.

new link:
https://plnkr.co/edit/InfM7lqCH1zPr2xSM7FF?p=preview

Comment: Where is the text you want to append to?

Comment: I'm a little confused, to clarify, when the user clicks the input box, with pre-existing text, you want the cursor to be at the end of the text so you can just add to it?

Comment: Please see edit